# Rails how to make profile form accept a user model attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user profile form which a user fills out after the user record has been created in the users database (via a users model). In the profile form along with the profile fields I have an email field which is actually from the users table. Here is my setup:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  ...

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  ...
```

In the profile form:

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :user do |l| %>
    <%= l.text_field :email, :placeholder => "email address" %>
  <% end %>
  ...
```

and in my profiles->new method, I have this..

```
profile.build_user
```

..now what happens is that a whole new user record is created when a profile is created. What I want is that when a profile is created, the email address should get updated in the users table for this user. Can someone spot the issue in my code? I suspect it's something to do with the last line of code i posted but not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the :accepts_nested_attributes_for method, I think this might be what you're looking for

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

in the user model you could have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile`